# Geometry / trig question

Tags: geometry

If I know the coordinates of $A$, $B$, $C$ and the angles $t$, $u$, $v$, how can I calculate the coordinates of the center point?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the center $O=(x,y,z)$, and radius by $r=|AO|$. Then we have $\vec{OA} \cdot \vec{OB}=r^2 \cos(u)$. Make use of the other two condition, we can determine a $3\times3$ linear system, which should be able to solve. I am not sure whether there is any better idea.